# Add class if one select's value is #

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    $("#bcscan").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("select").val() === '#') {
            $(this).addClass("warning");
        }
        else {
            ajaxPost(); 
        }
    });

});
```

I'm using following function, how can I modify it to add class `warning`, if **one of** `select` element's value = "#"?

Currently it's adding warning class to all selects

Comment: What would `this` refer to in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may be what you want:

```
$('select').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).val() === '#');
}).addClass('warning');
```

That selects all `select` elements, filters it down to those elements whose current value is equal to `#`, then adds the `warning` class to that subset.

---

I'll leave my original answer here, though given the changes to the question it's likely no longer relevant. This is my last stab at guessing what it is you want - if this is useful to you, great; if not, oh well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    $("#bcscan").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var doAjaxPost = true;
        $('select').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() === '#') {
                doAjaxPost = false;
                $(this).addClass('warning');
            }
        });
        if(doAjaxPost) {
            ajaxPost(); 
        }
    });

});
```

That checks all `select` elements when the form is submitted - if any of them have a value of `#` it adds the `warning` class to that select element. If none of them have a value of `#` it goes ahead and calls the ajaxPost() function.

Comment: Seems like your solution is the only one that matches the question now. +1

Comment: But how to call this function? It will be automatically called by script. But I want to get return value from this function and if all right continue posting data via ajax

Comment: @epic_syntax I've edited my answer to include something that's possibly closer to what I think you want.

Comment: Based on the current question, putting this in the `.submit()` function appears to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select').change(function (event) {
    if ($(this).val() === '#') $(this).addClass('warning');
});
```

`this` is populated with the element that fired the event. In this case the select.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/tNhKe/

Edit to match the question:

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    $("#bcscan").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var invalidCount = $('select').filter(function() {
            return ($(this).val() === '#');
        }).addClass('warning').length;

        if (invalidCount == 0) {
            alert('valid');
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/QxBH9/

Comment: Why do you update your question with an „entirely“ different question afterwards?

Comment: What's "entirely different"? Same thing I'm asking for

Comment: Thats why the entirely was in quotes. Your edit basically changes the whole question and possible answers.

Comment: @epic_syntax I'm with TimWolla on this one, the update has changed the question completely. It's still also not really that clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($("select:selected").val() == '#') {
        $("select").addClass("warning");
    }
```

http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: This will add the class to every select as well.